# Android load data from Firebase to a CalendarView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendarview

So this may be simple but I don't really know. I want to add data from Firebase database to a CalendarView. For example, I have a `date` and `title` saved in Firebase. How can I now add this to my CalendarView?

I know how to use FirebaseAdapters and how to get the data, but not how to add it to a CalendarView.

Can this be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried anything on your own yet? If so, do post the codes you have so far. And do tell if there were any errors you've run into. :)

Comment: I have not come so far all I managed to do I to initialize the calenderview, setting up minDate and some basic stuff. On problem is how can I draw the circle that indicates selected day on days that are fetched from Firebase? Need to solve the drawing first, The firebase **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** is done but the drawing is the problem.